SignInWithAppleButton throws onCompletion failure(Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1001 "(null)")
I'm new to swiftUi and I'm trying to implement "continue with apple" functionality but I'm getting this error and I have already added "Sign in with Apple" capability, please let me know if I made any mistake in implementation.
Error:
onCompletion failure(Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1001 "(null)")

Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1001 "(null)"

My Code:
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

@AppStorage("email") var email : String = ""
@AppStorage("firstName") var firstName : String = ""
@AppStorage("lastName") var lastName : String = ""
@AppStorage("userId") var userID : String = ""

SignInWithAppleButton(.continue, onRequest: {request in
                            request.requestedScopes = [.email, .fullName]
                            print("onRequest")
                        }, onCompletion: { result in
                            print("onCompletion", result)
                            switch result {
                            case .success(let auth):
                                print("onCompletion", auth)
                                switch auth.credential {
                                case let credential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
                                    let userId = credential.user
                                    let email = credential.email
                                    let firstName = credential.fullName?.givenName
                                    let lastName = credential.fullName?.familyName
                                    
                                    
                                    self.email = email ?? ""
                                    self.firstName = firstName ?? ""
                                    self.lastName = lastName ?? ""
                                    self.userID = userId
                                    
                                default:
                                    break
                                }
                            case .failure(let error):
                                print(error)
                            }
                        })
                        .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                        .frame(height: 50).padding().cornerRadius(30)


Did you test it on Simulators?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationerror/code/canceled

Yes sonle, I was testing in simulator and I understood the issue now, I checked Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles and sign in with apple was not checked. And thank you koen
